# How to push object with an array into an array in JS

Tags: javascript

See `jobs` in the log? It's not an array, how to push it as an array (so I can access it via loop).

https://jsfiddle.net/1jo43e8c/1/

```
var name = "John"
var age = 30
var jobs = ['a', 'b', 'c']

obj = []

obj.push('{name: "'+name+'", age: "'+age+'", jobs: '+jobs+'}')

console.log(obj) // result: ["{name: "John", age: "30", jobs: a,b,c}"]    
/////////////////// goal: ["{name: "John", age: "30", jobs: ["a","b","c"]}"]
```

Comment: Not sure what you're after, but using `JSON.stringify()` instead of your custom serialization might help.

Comment: Why are you building JSON manually? If you want to push a JSON string, why not prepare it as a proper object then push it via `JSON.stringify()`?

Comment: `obj.push(JSON.stringify({name, age, jobs}))` should do what you need

Comment: I do not understand your question, you want to push an object in a table is that?

Comment: `jobs: '+jobs+'` this calls `toString()` method on array. As @VladimirBogomolov mentioned you don't need string concatenation to create an object

Comment: I see now, thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JSON.stringify` ?

```
obj.push('{name: "'+name+'", age: "'+age+'", jobs: '+ JSON.stringify(jobs)+'}')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is

```
obj.push({jobs:['a', 'b', 'c'], age:30, name:'John'})
```

Also take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 0):

Use map on array.

```js
var name = "John"
var age = 30
var jobs = ['a', 'b', 'c']
obj = [];
let temp = jobs.map((v) => `"${v}"`);
obj.push(`{name: ${name}, age: ${age}, jobs: [${temp.join(",")}]}`)
console.log(obj) // ["{name: "John", age: "30", jobs: a,b,c}"]
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is map the array and then change the value of each item before push into obj.

```
var name = "John"
var age = 30
var jobs = ['a', 'b', 'c']
jobs = jobs.map(item => `"${item}"` );

obj = []

obj.push('{name: "'+name+'", age: "'+age+'", jobs: ['+jobs+']}')


console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives what you want.

```js
var name = "John"
var age = 30
var jobs = ['a', 'b', 'c']

var obj = []

obj.push(`{name: '${name}', age: '${age}', jobs: [${JSON.stringify(jobs)}}]`)



console.log(obj)   
// goal: ["{name: "John", age: "30", jobs: [a,b,c]}"]
```